# Decode bytes in string to bytes array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I get the data from txt file that look like this: `b'4\x00\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\xf1\x00\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\x00\x00\n\x00d\x00,\x01,\x01^\x01\x00\x01d\x00'`.

This is a string and I need to decode(encode) this string to byte array in a such way so the output will be exactly the same characters in new bytes array. I have tried
`converted_bytes = bytes(bytes_data, encoding = "raw_unicode_escape")`

but I get the result that look something like this:
`b"b'4\\x00\\xe8\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00.\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xf1\\x00\\xc0\\x03\\xc0\\x03\\xc0\\x03\\x00\\x00\\n\\x00d\\x00,\\x01,\\x01^\\x01\\x00\\x01d\\x00'"`.

So I need the same result but without double backslashes or some efficient way how to get rid of

Comment: Wouldn't the same thing without double backslashes just be what you started with?

Comment: @Coddo I need to decode each 16 bits from this bytes array to integer after. If there is the way how to decode hex string number to an int it will help

Comment: Have you looked into `int.from_bytes`?

Answer (score 0):

If its the case that you had a `bytes` variable and converted it to a string to write to a file, now you want the `bytes` variable back again. I think you can use `ast`:

```py
import ast

b = b'4\x00\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\xf1\x00\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\x00\x00\n\x00d\x00,\x01,\x01^\x01\x00\x01d\x00'

s = str(b)
# write to a file, then read file

b1 = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you've saved the file `python_byte_code.txt` with a content like the following:
`b'4\x00\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\xf1\x00\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\x00\x00\n\x00d\x00,\x01,\x01^\x01\x00\x01d\x00'`
(actual strings that you can see from a text editor)

Then you have a python file `script.py` that loads the content.
Since that `b'4\x00....\x00'` thing above is exactly how it would appear if it were a python code, you can use `eval` to create an actual `bytes` object from that string.

```
txt_file = open("python_byte_code.txt", "r")
file_content = txt_file.read()
print(file_content) # b'4\x00\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\xf1\x00\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\x00\x00\n\x00d\x00,\x01,\x01^\x01\x00\x01d\x00'
print(type(file_content)) # <class 'str'>

converted_bytes = eval(file_content)
print(converted_bytes ) # b'4\x00\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\xf1\x00\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\xc0\x03\x00\x00\n\x00d\x00,\x01,\x01^\x01\x00\x01d\x00'
print(type(converted_bytes)) # <class 'bytes'>
print(list(converted_bytes)) # [52, 0, 232, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 46, 0, 0, 0, 241, 0, 192, 3, 192, 3, 192, 3, 0, 0, 10, 0, 100, 0, 44, 1, 44, 1, 94, 1, 0, 1, 100, 0]
```

But be careful with `eval` especially when you take an input from another user.